# How would I do a for loop that waits until my function has completed for each loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

My current code is this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split("\n");

for(i in file) {
    var [thing1, thing2, thing3] = file[i].split(":");
    myfunction(thing1, thing2, thing3);
}
```

This executes a function for each line in the file with some info from the file. For technical reasons, I can only have the function running once at a time.
How can I make the for loop wait for the function to complete before looping again?

Comment: Function **will** run one at a time unless they are asynchronous. What is `myfunction()`? What does it do? is it an asynchronous function?

Comment: Assuming that `myfunction()` is synchronous (doesn't return a `Promise` and isn't marked as `async`) it will already wait. Otherwise, you can use `async`/`await` to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

if myfunction is sync one, your code is already working

other wise:

```
await myfunction(thing1, thing2, thing3);
```

make sure you add **async** to your block of code:

```
(async () => {
  for(i in file) {
     var [thing1, thing2, thing3] = file[i].split(":");
     await myfunction(thing1, thing2, thing3);
}})();
```

Comment: i added that, but now my console returns nothing. (im assuming because the function was never ran)

Comment: You should add that to derive any benefit from `await`, `myfunction()` MUST return a promise that is linked to when it completes its asynchronous operations.  If it doesn't return such a promise, then the `await` is useless and doesn't do anything.

Comment: (sorry if this is a dumb question im new to js) how do i know the function will return a promise?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make `myfunction` `await`-able like this:

```
async function myfunction (thing1, thing2, thing3) {
    // perform your operations here
    return 'done'; // return your results like object or string or whatever
}
```

So that it can for loop can wait for its completion on each iteration, like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split("\n");

// This main function is just a wrapper to initialize code
async function main() {
    for(i in file) {
        let [thing1, thing2, thing3] = file[i].split(":");
        let result = await myfunction(thing1, thing2, thing3);
            console.log(`Result of ${i} returned`);
    }
}

main();
```

For complete running example clone [node-cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/loop-await/loop-await.js#L14) and run `node loop-await.js`.